# page numbers being shown in the first page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I've created an image search website using unsplash api and I've added pagination. The problem is that when I search for an image, all the page numbers are in the first page. Suppose, there are 2000 pages of search results then all the page number buttons are shown in the first page. However when I click on any page number then it all works fine. I want that in the first page too, the page numbers are shown normally, like `prev, 1,2,....5,next`. I've given the `page=1` to the `fetchPosts` function. However that doesn't seem to solve the issue. Also, it works fine on the initial loading of the website. The problem shows up when you search for something. How do I solve this problem?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Pagination from "./Pagination";
import List from "./List";
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

const LOAD_STATE = {
  SUCCESS: "SUCCESS",
  ERROR: "ERROR",
  LOADING: "LOADING"
};

const appId =
  "22b7b54287910389edfae878f576488bbc5b540a46daa0d2833ba858ce03b143";
const BASE_URL = "https://api.unsplash.com/photos?page=1";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.fetchPhotos = this.fetchPhotos.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      photos: [],
      totalPhotos: 0,
      perPage: 5,
      currentPage: 1,
      loadState: LOAD_STATE.LOADING,
      search: ""
    };
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchPhotos(this.state.currentPage);
  }

  fetchPhotos(page = 1) {
    var self = this;
    const { search, perPage } = this.state;
    const url1 = `https://api.unsplash.com/photos?page=${page}&client_id=${appId}`;
    const url2 =
      `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=${page}&query=` +
      search +
      "&client_id=" +
      appId;
    const url = search ? url2 : url1;

    if (search) {
      const options = {
        params: {
          page: page,
          per_page: perPage,
          order_by: "popularity"
        }
      };

      this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.LOADING });
      axios
        .get(url, options)
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({
            photos: response.data.results,
            totalPhotos: parseInt(response.headers["x-total"]),
            currentPage: page,
            loadState: LOAD_STATE.SUCCESS
          });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.ERROR });
        });
    } else {
      const options = {
        params: {
          client_id: appId,
          page: page,
          per_page: perPage,
          order_by: "popularity"
        }
      };

      this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.LOADING });
      axios
        .get(url, options)
        .then(response => {
          self.setState({
            photos: response.data,
            totalPhotos: parseInt(response.headers["x-total"]),
            currentPage: page,
            loadState: LOAD_STATE.SUCCESS
          });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.ERROR });
        });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <input
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          type="text"
          name="search"
          placeholder="Enter query"
        />
        <button type="submit" onClick={this.fetchPhotos} className="button">
          Submit
        </button>
        <Pagination
          current={this.state.currentPage}
          total={this.state.totalPhotos}
          perPage={this.state.perPage}
          onPageChanged={this.fetchPhotos.bind(this)}
        />
        {this.state.loadState === LOAD_STATE.LOADING ? (
          <div className="loader" />
        ) : (
          <List data={this.state.photos} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Pagination

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Pagination extends Component {
  pages() {
    var pages = [];
    for (var i = this.rangeStart(); i <= this.rangeEnd(); i++) {
      pages.push(i);
    }
    return pages;
  }

  rangeStart() {
    var start = this.props.current - this.props.pageRange;
    return start > 0 ? start : 1;
  }

  rangeEnd() {
    var end = this.props.current + this.props.pageRange;
    var totalPages = this.totalPages();
    return end < totalPages ? end : totalPages;
  }

  totalPages() {
    return Math.ceil(this.props.total / this.props.perPage);
  }

  nextPage() {
    return this.props.current + 1;
  }

  prevPage() {
    return this.props.current - 1;
  }

  hasFirst() {
    return this.rangeStart() !== 1;
  }

  hasLast() {
    return this.rangeEnd() < this.totalPages();
  }

  hasPrev() {
    return this.props.current > 1;
  }

  hasNext() {
    return this.props.current < this.totalPages();
  }

  changePage(page) {
    this.props.onPageChanged(page);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="pagination">
        <div className="pagination__left">
          <a
            href="#"
            className={!this.hasPrev() ? "hidden" : ""}
            onClick={e => this.changePage(this.prevPage())}
          >
            Prev
          </a>
        </div>

        <div className="pagination__mid">
          <ul>
            <li className={!this.hasFirst() ? "hidden" : ""}>
              <a href="#" onClick={e => this.changePage(1)}>
                1
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className={!this.hasFirst() ? "hidden" : ""}>...</li>
            {this.pages().map((page, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index}>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    onClick={e => this.changePage(page)}
                    className={this.props.current == page ? "current" : ""}
                  >
                    {page}
                  </a>
                </li>
              );
            })}
            <li className={!this.hasLast() ? "hidden" : ""}>...</li>
            <li className={!this.hasLast() ? "hidden" : ""}>
              <a href="#" onClick={e => this.changePage(this.totalPages())}>
                {this.totalPages()}
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div className="pagination__right">
          <a
            href="#"
            className={!this.hasNext() ? "hidden" : ""}
            onClick={e => this.changePage(this.nextPage())}
          >
            Next
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Pagination.defaultProps = {
  pageRange: 2
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you using with 2 different ways the `fetchPhotos` function

```
  onClick={this.fetchPhotos}
```

In this senario, you don't pass the page number but rather the event so it can't know which page you are. Change it to this and it should work.
I guess for every submit of button, it should default to first page.

```
<button
  type="submit"
  onClick={() => this.fetchPhotos(1)}
  className="button"
>
```

Comment: thanks. that worked. also, the downloading of the images aren't working even when I added the <a download>. can you please help with that?

Comment: hmm not quite sure why this is not working because I have similar code in my app too in order to download pdf files. maybe it is browser-centric? "display images in browser"? sth like that?

Comment: I read that download doesn't work with cross origin sources anymore. i guess i will post a new question regarding this

Comment: A ok, great. didn't know that. my button was for same server request so that's why i don't have problem with that :)